# Why do I see display lag when I press a button or pressable to change two images?

Tags: react-native, expo

https://youtu.be/DlT8yiPgEvQ

I'm new to expo and react native and beginning to grasp conditional rendering. The behavior demonstrated in the video clip, however, is extremely frustrating. Why is react native showing this kind of behavior? I am currently making an expo test app and testing it on my macbook pro with an ios simulator. The problem I have is that a conditionally rendered element, such as image, lags before rendering completely. As you can see in the video clip, The image wrapped in pressable should change both its source and position in the screen as soon as the state variable changes its value. However, it seems that it first displays the new pressable image at its original position and then moves the image according to top: decimal (also displaying the entire position-shifting process). What I want is the entire image to be displayed only after its position is adjusted as well. I don't want to see the display lag every time I press a button to change an image. I highly appreciate your insight, and below is my source code.

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { Pressable, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View, ScrollView, Image, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';
import login from './login-screen.png';
import loginButton from './login-screen-button.png';
import loginButtonPressed from './loginButton2.png';
import ID_selected from './ID_selected.png';
import {useState} from 'react';

//Iphone 12 pro max resolution: 1284 x 2778 pixels

export default function App() {
  const win = Dimensions.get('window');
  const ratio = win.width / 428;
  const [text, onChangeText] = useState();
  const [isShowingImageID, setShowingImageID] = useState(false);
  const [isShowingImagePW, setShowingImagePW] = useState(false);
  const [pressed, onPressFunction] = useState(false);
  console.log("Window.width: ", win.width);
  console.log("Windows.height: ", win.height);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {/* style={{
        flexGrow: 1,
      }} */}
      {/*428*/} 
      {/*926*/}
      <Image
        source={login}
        style={{
          width: 428, //428
          height: 926, //926
          //aspectRatio: 1,
        }}
      />
      <Pressable 
        onPressIn={() => onPressFunction(true)}
        onPressOut={() => onPressFunction(false)}
        style={{
          position: "absolute"
          //aspectRatio: 1,
        }}
      >
        {
          pressed ? 
          (
            <Image
              source={loginButtonPressed}
              style={{
                width: 428, //428
                height: 926, //926
                top: 50,
                position: "relative"
              }}
            />
          ) :
          (
            <Image
              source={loginButton}
              style={{
                width: 428, //428
                height: 926, //926
                //aspectRatio: 1,
                position: "relative"
              }}
            />
          )
        }
      </Pressable>
      
      {
        isShowingImageID ?
        (
          <Image
            source={ID_selected}
            //1184 x 140
            style={{
              width: 1184 / 3, 
              height: 140 / 3, 
              //aspectRatio: 1,
              position: "absolute",
              top: 295
            }}
          />
         ) : (null)
      }
      {
        isShowingImagePW ?
        (
          <Image
            source={ID_selected}
            //1184 x 140
            style={{
              width: 1184 / 3, 
              height: 140 / 3, 
              //aspectRatio: 1,
              position: "absolute",
              top: 338
            }}
          />
         ) : (null)
      }
      <TextInput
        style={textInputStyleID.container}
        onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}
        onPressIn={touchEvt => setShowingImageID(true)}
        onPressOut={touchEvt => setShowingImageID(false)}
        //value={text} //Since onChangeText is used for both ID and PW, using either text input
        //will constantly update text, which only has one instance. Thus, setting value
        //to text will change both text inputs.
        placeholder="아이디"
        placeholderTextColor="#A9A9A9"
        keyboardType="email-address"
      />
      <TextInput
        style={textInputStylePW.container}
        onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}
        onPressIn={touchEvt => setShowingImagePW(true)}
        onPressOut={touchEvt => setShowingImagePW(false)}
        //value={text}
        placeholder="비밀번호"
        placeholderTextColor="#A9A9A9"
        keyboardType="default"
        secureTextEntry={true}
      />
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    position: 'absolute'
  },
});
const textInputStyleID = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 303,
    left: 42,
    width: 350,
    height: 30
  }
});
const textInputStylePW = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 346,
    left: 42,
    width: 350,
    height: 30
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than this

```
 <Pressable 
        onPressIn={() => onPressFunction(true)}
        onPressOut={() => onPressFunction(false)}
        style={{
          position: "absolute"
          //aspectRatio: 1,
        }}
      >
```

can you try this using just `onPress`?

```
 <Pressable 
        onPress={() => onPressFunction(true)}
        style={{
          position: "absolute"
          //aspectRatio: 1,
        }}
      >
```

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: onPress does not fit my purposes though. I need to switch between two separate images. One for holding the button and one for releasing the finger.

Comment: so whats going wrong? when you are pressing in you see a lag in image switch?

Comment: Yes, <Image source={loginButtonPressed} style={{ width: 428, height: 926, top: 50, position: "relative" }} /> is supposed to appear right away as soon as I press on the login button. However, if you can see in the video, it moves upwards and downwards before fixing its position permanently as instructed by top: 50. I want the new image to appear right away in a position I desire without moving upwards or downwards.

Comment: Btw, the position lag appears for both onPressIn and onPressOut.

Comment: @rasputin can you share an expo snack? will check there

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/vD-FQyssM 
Hmm interesting. The snack works in web but simply refuses to work in any type of ios simulator.
When testing on an iphone 12 pro max simulator provided by xcode, there's the position delay lag I mentioned. When testing on the snack ios simulator, it does not even render all the images properly.